# Regarding convergence in product metric spaces (and Rudin's ex. 4.6) without notions from topology

Tags: real-analysis, continuity, metric-spaces, proof-explanation

I was skimming through my proof of Rudin's ex. 4.6 and came with questions regarding convergence in product metric spaces. Assume that I do not have any knowledge in general topology, besides Rudin's ch. 2 and am self-studying. I will highlight sentences about which I would like to know if they are justified.

> If $E$ is compact, prove that $f$ is continuous on $E$ if and only if its graph is compact.

> Assume $f$ is continuous. Let $\mathcal G$ be the graph of $f$. Define a one-to-one correspondence $h \colon E \to \mathcal G$ as $h(x) = (x,f(x))$ $(x \in E)$. If $p \in E$ is any, we have $f(x) \to f(p)$ as $x \to p$, $\color{blue}{\text{so $(x,f(x)) \to (p,f(p))$ as $x \to p$}}$. This proves that $h$ is continuous, and therefore, since $E$ is compact, $h(E)=\mathcal G$ is compact.

> On the contrary, assume $\mathcal G$ is compact. Let $x\in E$ and $x_n\to x$ be any. The tuples $(x_n,f(x_n))$ form a sequence in $\mathcal G$. $\color{blue}{\text{If $(x_n,f(x_n))\to(x,f(x))$, we are done, since then $f(x_n)\to f(x)$}}$. So assume $(x_n,f(x_n))\nrightarrow (x,f(x))$. We can find a subsequence $(x_{n_i},f(x_{n_i}))\to (x,y)\in\mathcal G$ ($y\neq f(x))$, since $\mathcal G$ is compact. But $(x,y)\in\mathcal G$ implies $y=f(x)$.

I know that when proving the first part we could define any metric on the product space of the graph and then use it. I didn't do it and, I think, made an unjustified inference regarding convergence, did I? If the metric is discrete, we could not even infer it at all, right?

And then to the second part. Having only the tools of Rudin's basic analysis, can we rigorously show that the second coordinate $f(x_n)$ in the tuple really converges? This is subtle, since we do not know about metric in $\mathcal G$; we could use common metric in product topology, but this metric is studied in topology, and Rudin does not have business with this notion. I don't think we could just define a metric in $\mathcal G$ before starting our proof, couldn't we?

I didn't highlight what comes when we assume $(x_n,f(x_n))\nrightarrow(x,f(x))$, but this part makes me doubt what comes next, too. I used the notion of compactness, that we can find a converging subsequence, then, using the fact that $x_n\to x$, I "know" that the tuple must look like $(x,y)$ where $y\neq f(x)$, is it justified?

Comment: How do you interpret convergence in the product space without an explicit metric or a topology? From what I saw there is no natural singular way to define a product metric, so you need some information on the metric or the topology.

Comment: @Keen-amaterus, are we allowed to define a metric on the graph before approaching this problem? I think so, but I am in doubt.

Comment: Not necessarily define, but have something to work with.  If you are not talking in the terminology of topology, what a metric on the product space a product metric? Which metric on the product space do you choose?

Comment: @Keen-ameteur I myself did not state any metric explicitly. You say not necessarily define; I saw a solution to this problem, where author turns the graph into a metric space by defining a metric. So, we are absolutely allowed to do it when we will work with, like, when we want to prove something about a "new" a bit unknown structure like graph in this one? Thinking that we have many metrics on $R$ and only use simple $|x-y|$ for whatever reasons in basic analysis, I guess, similarly, we can use any metric which will work here, like $d_{\mathcal G}((x,f(x)),(y,f(y)))=d_X(x,y)+d_Y(f(x),f(y))$?

Comment: Or, similarly saying, that author introduced something to work with.

Comment: But the importance is that those metric satisfy a property. The metric you gave induces the product topology. There is no canonical product metric.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So perhaps I will try to write an explanation to the points you asked?

I assume you have metric spaces $(X,d_X)$ and $(Y,d_Y)$. The metric on the product space will be any metric $\rho$ on $X\times Y$ inducing the product topology. For example, $\rho\big( (x_1,y_1), (x_2,y_2) \big)=d_X(x_1,x_2)+d_Y(y_1,y_2)$ does the job.

Then $(x_n,y_n)\to (x,y)$ if and only if $x_n\to x$ and $y_n \to y$.

Then $\big( x_n, f(x_n) \big)\to (p,f(p))$ in $\mathcal{G}$ if and only if $x_n\to p$ and $f(x_n)\to f(x)$.

To your first question, if $d_X$ is not discrete then $\rho$ **cannot** be discrete.

To the second point, any suitable product metric you work with here must imply convergence in the second coordinate.

You either fix a topological structure and choose a corresponding metric, or you have a fixed metric. I don't see how you can avoid have this basic amount of information.